# Does curvature invariance imply isometry?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I have a few questions, for which I have been trying to find a reference  to no avail. They are somewhat related. Please provide references if possible.

In what follows $(U,g)$ and $(V,h)$ are two n-dim Riemannian manifolds and assume that $f:U\to V$ is a diffeomorphism.  My questions are of local or semi-global nature, so please assume that all sets/manifolds are homeomorphic to a disk.

The first question seems to me to be be the real content of famous Theorema Egregium. It believe it is true, but I could not find a reference for it.

1) Assume that $n=2$ and that $K_g(x) = K_h(f(x))$ for all $x\in U$. Then is it true that $f$ is an isometry? Here, $K_g(x)$ stands for the Gaussian curvature of  the metric $g$ at point $x$.

The second question relates to a generalization of 1) to higher dimensions

2) Assume that the pull back of the Riemann curvature tensor of $h$ under $f$ coincides with the Riemann curvature tensor of $g$. Is $f$ an isometry?

Now I will try to express question 2) in local coordinates, for a very simple case:

3) Assume $U=V \subset {\mathbb R}^n$ and $f=id$. Assume that the Riemann curvature tensor of the two metrics $g$ and $h$ coincide pointwise. Is then $g=h$?

Please note that a similar question can be  formulated for the Riemann curvature tensor of (0,4) or (1,3) types. So two questions in one question:

3.1) If $R^i_{.jkl} (g)\equiv R^i_{.jkl}(h)$ for all indices, does it follow that $g=h$?  Please note that there is no constancy assumption on curvature, only point-wise identities between the curvatures of the two metrics.

3.2) The same question as in 3.1), this time assuming $R_{ijkl} (g)\equiv R_{ijkl}(h)$.

4) Finally, coming back to the simplest case I am interested in:  Assume $U=V \subset {\mathbb R}^2$ and that the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{jk}(g) \equiv \Gamma^i_{jk}(h)$, as a pointwise identity. Does it follow that $f=g$?

Of course 3.1) $\implies$ 4).

Comment: Most of the answers to your questions are here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100281/does-the-curvature-determine-the-metric

Comment: "homemorphic to a disk" would force $\:n=2\;$. $\;\;$ Do you mean homeomorphic to a ball? $\hspace{1.19 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: "disk" is sometimes also used as synonim with "ball" (as in "$n$-dimensional disk")

Answer (score 3):

The answer to all questions is "no". Example for 1), 2): 
both spaces are discs in the plane with
the standard metric. The curvature is 0.  $f$ is any diffeomorphism of the disc, which
is not an isometry. Example for 3): same unit disc. One metric is standard,
another is $p(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$, where $p$ is any harmonic function. The curvature is $0$
for both metrics.