# What is the relation between two Riemannian metrics with the same Riemannian curvatures?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Consider two flat Riemannian metrics on a manifold. What is the general relation between these two metrics if the manifold is not simply-connected? What is the answer if two Riemannian metrics have the same non-flat Riemannian curvature?

Can anyone suggest me relevant references that deal with this problem?

Thanks,
Arzhang

Comment: Relevant :http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100281/does-the-curvature-determine-the-metric?rq=1