# Given $Ric_g$ of 3-dim Riemannian manifold, induced metric $\gamma$ and mean curvature $tr_{\gamma}K$ on a hypersurface, do we have $K$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have the manifold $\mathbb{R}^3$ equipped with a Riemanian metric $g$ (not necessarily the Euclidean metric. And the induced metric on the $B_1$ (the ball with radius $1$) is $\gamma$.

Suppose we are given $Ric_g$, $\gamma$, and $tr_{\gamma} K$, where $K$ is the second fundamental form. Can we find $K$? (We don’t know $g$).

Here is my progress: 
All we need to find is the traceless part of $K$ which I denote by $\hat{K}$. Then $K = \hat{K} + \frac12 (tr_{\gamma}K) \gamma$.

Choose a coordinate system $(x_0, x_1, x_2)$ where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}$ is normal to $B_1$ and is of unit length (so $g_{00} = 1$).  Then the following equations are true:

$$R_g - 2Ric_{00} = R_{\gamma} - \frac12 (tr_{\gamma}K)^2 + |\hat{K}|^2 $$ 
$$R_{0i} = D^l \hat{K}_{il} - \frac12 D_i (tr_{\gamma} K)$$
Where $D$ is the covariant derivative on $B_1$ and $|\hat{K}|^2 = \hat{K}_{ij} \hat{K}^{ij}.$

So in other words, we know $|\hat{K}|^2$ and $D^l \hat{K}_{il}$ (since we know everything else in these equations). Does that uniquely determine $\hat{K}$?

Also notice that these are three functions but $\hat{K}$ is compromised of only 2 distinct functions. Is this overdetermined? More precisely, given any positive function $h$ and any 1-form $\omega_i$, does there exist a unique symmetric traceless (0,2) tensor on $B_1$ such that $h = |\hat{K}|^2$ and $\omega_{i} = D^l \hat{K}_{il}$ ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the discussion here may or may not be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/100281/138661

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is 'no' even if $g$ is the standard flat metric.  Indeed, it is well known that there are isometric *minimal* surfaces (the catenoid and the helicoid) such that the isometry between them does not align their second fundamental forms.  Thus, knowing $Ric_g=0$ and $\mathrm{tr}_\gamma K = 0$ and knowing $\gamma$ on the surface is not (always) enough to determine $K$.

This is an unusual case though.  The set of surface metrics that can be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ in two ways so that they each induce the same mean curvature function is a very small set of all metrics (at least up to diffeomorphism).

(By the way, using $K$ to denote the second fundamental form is bound to lead to confusion, since $K$ is usually reserved for the Gauss curvature of the surface metric $\gamma$.)