# Possible curvatures of the topological sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Consider the family $\mathbb{S}$ of compact oriented surfaces homeomorphic to the 2-sphere $\mathcal{S} = S^2$. Consider arbitrary continuous mappings $k: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which obey the condition $\int_\mathcal{S} k = 4\pi$. The latter looks like the Gauss-Bonnet condition for 2-spheres, and that's why I want to call those mappings “curvature-like”.

> For which curvature-like mappings $k$
>   does exist a surface $S \in
> > \mathbb{S}$ which $k$ is the Gaussian curvature of?

In other words: For which curvature-like mappings $k$
does exist a surface $S \in
\mathbb{S}$ with a homeomorphism $s: S \rightarrow \mathcal{S} $ such that
$k \circ s$ equals the Gaussian curvature $\kappa: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

**Background (and for comparison's sake)**: When one considers (plane) Jordan curves - which are homeomorphic to the 1-sphere $S^1$ - and continuous “curvature-like” mappings $k: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which obey the condition $\int_{S^1} k = 2\pi$ – in accordance to [Hopf's Umlaufsatz](http://warwickmaths.org/files/Curvature.pdf#page=4) – then the additional condition for a curvature-like mapping to be a “real” curvature seems to be given by the [four-vertex theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280308/1792).

Comment: This question was studied by Gluck, if I remember correctly. Keep in mind that the area form will also vary with the metric, so as long as the integral of a continuous function on the sphere is positive, you can arrange that it is the curvature of a Riemannian metric.

Comment: @Ben: Would this imply, that *every* curvature-like mapping can be the curvature of some topological sphere? Even for other integral values than $4\pi$?

Comment: @Ben, you wanted to say "if the function is positive at one point", not "as long as the integral ... is positive". If I remember right the same holds for Scalar curvature in higher dimensions, but I do not remember a ref.

Comment: @Anton: correct: positive at one point. No need to look at the integral. @Hans: correct, for any integral. 

Comment: @Ben, @Anton: Thank you very much. A reference would be welcome!

Comment: I don't understand how you are integrating $k$ over the $2$-sphere, since you can't integrate functions without having a measure specified.  The integral constraint makes no sense without it.  Similarly, for a $1$-sphere you can't integrate $\kappa$ without having a measure on the $1$-sphere, i.e., an arc-length.  Even when you do specify an arclength $ds$ as well as $\kappa$, it is certainly *not* enough to require that $\int\kappa\ ds=2\pi$ and that $\kappa$ have at least $4$ critical points in order for there to be a curve in the plane with that curvature and arclength.

Comment: (continued).  Actually make that a *closed* curve in the plane with that curvature and arclength.

Comment: See also the earlier MO question, "Determining a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by its Gaussian curvature" http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76955/ , which cites the paper by Gluck, Krigelman, and Singer, entitled "The converse to the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem in PL."

Answer (score 5):

Kazdan, Jerry L. and Warner, F. W., Existence and conformal deformation of metrics with prescribed Gaussian and scalar curvatures, Ann. of Math. (2), 101, 1975, pp. 317--331 prove that a $C^{\infty}$ function $K$ on the 2-sphere is the Gauss curvature of a $C^{\infty}$ Riemannian metric if and only if $K$ is positive at at least one point of the sphere. In the same paper, they prove that if $M$ is a compact manifold of dimension 3 or more, and $K$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function on $M$, and $K$ is somewhere negative then $K$ is the scalar curvature of a $C^{\infty}$ Riemannian metric, while is $K$ is nowhere negative, then $K$ is the scalar curvature of a $C^{\infty}$ Riemannian metric if and only if $M$ admits a Riemannian metric of constant positive scalar curvature.

Comment: Thank you very much. (Here is a link: http://www.kfki.hu/~iracz/sgimp/cikkek/KazdanWarner.pdf)

Comment: I think the last statement is not quite correct as $K$ could be the zero function, in which case $M$ could be a Ricci-flat manifold which does not admit psc metrics, e.g. a K3 surface or a torus.