# Possible curvatures of the topological torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Consider the family $\mathbb{T}$ of compact oriented surfaces homeomorphic to the torus $\mathcal{T} = S^1 \times S^1$. Consider arbitrary continuous mappings $k: \mathcal{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which obey the condition $\int_\mathcal{T} k = 0$.

> For which curvature-like mappings $k$
>   does exist a surface $T \in
> > \mathbb{T}$ which $k$ is the Gaussian curvature of?

For the [topological sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122835/possible-curvatures-of-the-topological-sphere) the answer seems to be: for all. Can the proof of the latter - which I do not know - be generalized for arbitrary compact oriented surfaces? Or is it already a general proof for arbitrary surfaces?

Comment: How are you integrating a function that takes values in $\mathbb T$?  $\mathbb T$ isn't a vector space, and what measure on $\mathcal T$ are you integrating with respect to? 

Comment: It sounds like you're asking the question, which functions $S^1 \times S^1 \to \mathbb R$ can be realized as Gauss curvatures for some Levi-Cevita connection on $S^1 \times S^1$ ? 

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry, this was a typo, it should have been $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Ryan: Is "Levi-Civita connection on $S^1\times S^1$" the same as "homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$"? If so: yes, that's what I am asking.

Comment: If you don't demand some regularity of your manifold your curvature could be a distribution rather than a continuous function.  That's why I'm asking what you mean by curvature -- curvature of what?  If it's the curvature of a Levi-Cevita connection presumably we're talking about smooth manifolds and fairly standard notions of curvature.  Your insistence on talking about *topological* manifolds is what's throwing me now. 

Comment: @Ryan: I have smooth manifolds and standard notions of curvature in  mind. How should I have made this clear?

Comment: For the future: Plaese use a tag with two-letter prefix if (and only if) it exists. [The list is to be found right below where you need to enter them in the first place.] Thanks in advance! 

Comment: One way to clarify the question would be to define the objects of $\mathbb{T}$ so as to have more structure: compact oriented surfaces, homeomorphic to the torus, and equipped with a smooth structure and a Riemannian metric.

Comment: One answer to the conundrum of the integral $\int_T k$ could be to treat curvature as a signed measure $\kappa$: If $S$ is a Riemannian surface, then $\kappa(E)=\int_E k(z)dA$, where $dA$ is the Riemannian area-density. This also works nicely if the Riemannian metric is singular as in Troyanov's work mentioned by Alexandre. Note that one usually fixes the conformal class of the Riemannian metric.  

Comment: The integral in the question doesn't make sense, because the measure that appears in the Gauss--Bonnet theorem is the one given by the Riemannian metric. The question you want to ask is: if $k$ is a smooth function on the torus, taking on both positive and negative values, is  $k$ the curvature of a Riemannian metric? The answer is yes: see 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is known for all smooth surfaces:
M. S. Berger, Riemannian structure of prescribed Gaussian curvature for compact 2-manifolds, J. Differential Geom. 5 (1971), 325-332.
J. Kazdan and F. Warner, Curvature functions for compact 2-manifolds, Ann. of Math. 99 (1974), 14-47.
(This deals with the case of torus).

All these results were generalized by Troyanov, 
Prescribing curvature on compact surfaces with conical singularities. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 324 (1991), no. 2, 793–821, who deals with surfaces with singularities,
and in another paper, with open surfaces.