# Smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not contained in real analytic surface?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds

Is there a $C^\infty$-smooth embedding $\gamma : I \to \mathbb{R}^3$  so that there is no real analytic $2$-dimensional submanifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\gamma(I)\subset M$?

Comment: Presumably you want $\gamma$ to be an embedding? Otherwise you can just arrange $\gamma(I)$ to have a triple self-intersection from three linearly independent directions.

Comment: @Willie Wong, Thanks, I fixed this!

Comment: Is $M$ allowed to have boundary, and does $M$ have to be embedded as well?

Comment: An obvious guess is to take a non-analytic curve in the plane e.g. $y = e^{-1/x}$ and "wiggle" it in the z-direction -- maybe have $z = e^{-1/x} \sin(1/x)$ or something. No idea how you'd prove it though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an example:  Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $\gamma(t) = \bigl(t,\exp(-1/t^2),0\bigr)$ for $t<0$, $\gamma(0) = (0,0,0)$ and $\gamma(t) = \bigl(t,0,\exp(-1/t^2)\bigr)$ for $t>0$.  Then I claim that there is no nonsingular real-analytic surface $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ that contains the image of $\gamma$.

To see this, suppose that such an $M$ does exist and let $u\in S^2$ be a unit normal to $M$ at the origin.  If $u\not=(0,0,\pm1)$, then $M$ and the plane $z=0$ intersect transversely at $(0,0,0)$ along a real-analytic curve that contains $\gamma\bigl((-\epsilon,0]\bigr)$ for some $\epsilon>0$, which is clearly impossible.  Similarly, we reach a contradiction if $u\not=(0,\pm1,0)$.  Thus, $M$ does not exist.

Comment: This a very elegant solution, thank you Robert!

Comment: @OtisChodosh:  You're welcome.  It's an intresting question.  I guess a related question is whether every smooth germ of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ lies in some $2$-dimensional (locally) real-analytic subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which may be singular).  I don't know how to answer that, but I do expect the answer to be 'no', even if you assume the curve to be smoothly embedded.

Comment: If I recall correctly, any curve of constant torsion can be embedded locally in a pseudospherical surface (which I think is analytic?).

Comment: @IanAgol:  Pseudospherical surfaces, by which people usually mean surfaces in $3$-space with constant negative Gauss curvature (though some sources specifically require Gauss curvature equal to $-1$), do not have to be analytic.  I believe it's true that any smooth space curve is locally contained in a (local) smooth surface of Gauss curvature $-1$.  In particular, the example that I gave above must lie in some smooth surface of Gauss curvature $-1$.  Meanwhile, smooth surfaces with Gauss curvature equal to $+1$ in $3$-space do have to be real-analytic.

Comment: @RobertBryant okay, thanks for the clarification, I didn’t realize that they aren’t necessarily analytic.

Comment: @IanAgol:  I meant to come back to your comment about curves of constant torsion.  A theorem of Beltrami and Enneper says that the square of the torsion of an asymptotic curve on a surface is the negative of the Gauss curvature of  the surface along the curve.  In particular, for a pseudospherical surface, the asymptotic curves have constant torsion.  A natural question is whether every curve of (nonzero) constant torsion $\tau$ is an asymptotic curve on a surface of constant Gauss curvature $-\tau^2$ (which may not be complete).  That seems plausible, but I don't know a proof.

Comment: @IanAgol:  Here's an interesting result:  It turns out that a (smooth, but I think that $C^3$ would suffice) space curve $\gamma$ of constant torsion equal to $1$ lies in a surface $S$ of constant Gauss curvature $-1$ in such a way that $\gamma$ is an asymptotic curve in $S$ if and only if the integral of its curvature $\kappa$ with respect to arc length $\mathrm{d}s$ between any two points of $\gamma$ is less than $\pi$.  This follows from the solvability of a doubly characteristic IVP for the Sine-Gordon Equation, plus the standard structure equations.

Comment: @CrashBandicoot:  I don't.  I'm not even sure what 'meager' means.

Comment: @CrashBandicoot:  Oh...OK.  I think that it is probably true that the 'generic' smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not contained in any analytic submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't know any literature about this.