# To what extent can I specify the angular defect at the vertices of a polyhedron?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Suppose $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and suppose $\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_n$ are positive real numbers, each less than $2\pi$, whose sum is $4\pi$. Is there a polyhedron $\mathcal P$ which has a vertex at $p_i$ of angular defect $\delta_i$ (meaning that the sum of the interior angles of the faces meeting at $p_i$ is $2\pi-\delta_i$) for each $i=1,\ldots, n$, and possibly some extra vertices all of whose angular defect $0$? That is, I am specifying some of the vertices and angular defects, but allowing the addition of extra vertices on the condition that those vertices have angular defect zero.

If so, is there a constructive proof? If not, are there known constraints on the points and/or defects?

The question can be extended more broadly: the condition that the defects are positive could be dropped and we could ask that $\delta_1+\cdots+\delta_n=2\pi \chi$.

Comment: Related: [Determining a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by its Gaussian curvature](https://mathoverflow.net/q/76955/6094).

Comment: I think (not certain) you are seeking [Alexandrov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov%27s_uniqueness_theorem)? In more detail: Bobenko, Alexander I., and Ivan Izmestiev. "Alexandrov’s theorem, weighted Delaunay triangulations, and mixed volumes." In *Annales de l'institut Fourier*, vol. 58, no. 2, pp. 447-505. 2008.

Comment: 1. Since $0<\delta_j<1$ your polyherdon must be convex therefore you must have $\chi=2$. 2. You cannot prescribe $\delta_j$ and $p_j$ simultaneously. The $\delta_j$ aready define the polyhedron up to scaling and rotation. The $p_j$ define the polyhedron up to finitely many choices.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I am allowing extra vertices with angular defect 0, so there should be infinitely many choice. I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke If I'm understanding it correctly, Alexandrov's Theorem deals with convex polyhedra, which $\mathcal P$ would not be if it has zero-angular-defect vertices (e.g. ones other than $p_1,\ldots,p_n$).

Comment: Zero curvature at a point just means flat. Alexandrov's theorem still applies. But I think it doesn't quite match your question. My misunderstanding; sorry. Once you specify the location of your points $p_i$, the curvatures at the vertices is determined.

Comment: Incidentally, your "angular defect" is more commonly known as (discrete) curvature.

Comment: @stepnp21: the changes you made do not help. You cannot prescribe both angular defects AND vertices. For example, if you have 4 angular defects each $=\pi$ then the polyhedron MUST be a regular tetrahedron, so you cannot prescribe vertices.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko If you take a cube and attach to four of its faces square-based pyramids whose triangular faces have angles $\pi/4$, $3\pi/8$, $3\pi/8$, then that gives another polyhedron with four vertices, each with angular defect $\pi$; I've added 8 vertices with angular defect 0 to accomplish this.